# A message from stack exchange concerning support for OpenID

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, login, openid

I received the  following message but  I am not sure that it is  a  real message  or  is  spam. Is it it  really  a message  from SE sent to  all participants?

"Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange are ending support for third party OpenID providers. Your immediate action is needed in order for your account to stay active.

Please click to add an email and password credential to your account.

Alternately you can associate your account with Google or Facebook via the same link.

OpenID will be no longer supported on July 25, 2018. If you haven’t updated your account before then you will lose access to your account."

Comment: I think it is spam.  I have not received such email.  Of course, send an email query to a trusted StackExchange contact to confirm.  Of course, don't click on the links in the suspect email. Gerhard "Don't Trust And Always Verify" Paseman, 2018.06.25.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Presumably, you don’t log in through a third party OpenID provider.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek  What does it  mean third  party Open ID provider?

Comment: It means an OpenID provider other than StackExchange itself.

Comment: I don't know what OpenID is. I use my Yahoo account to login to StackExchange. Should I do something to continue in SE?

Comment: @PVanchinathan I log in the same way. Just to be safe, I added a stackexchange email+password login method here https://mathoverflow.net/users/mylogins/me

Answer (score 17):

The message is real. Its content matches the post [Support for OpenID ends on July 25, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-25-2018) by a Stack Exchange employee.

It was not sent to *all* participants, only to those whose login method is being phased out. Another SE employee [tweeted](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1011302046656618496):

> Heads up: we're about to send an email out to about 120,000 users who *only* have an OpenID to login to Stack Exchange. We'll be removing OpenID support from our code entirely in 30 days. This is for .NET Core, testability, and our sanity.